# sqlite find time between two times problem with midnight time

Tags: sqlite, datetime, time

I have two times in table - open_time and close time.

```
Open_time.  Selected time  Close_time
06:00:00    09:23:46       23:45:00
09:00:00    09:23:46       00:00:00
09:00:00    09:23:46       23:00:00
09:00:00    09:23:46       23:00:00
06:00:00    09:23:46       23:45:00
06:00:00    09:23:46       04:00:00
06:00:00    09:23:46       02:00:00
```

I need select only that time which between open and close, but my expression
have some problem.

```
SELECT open_from, close_at FROM restrnt WHERE (time('now', '+10 hours') BETWEEN  restaurants.open_from and restaurants.close_at)

06:00:00    23:45:00
09:00:00    23:00:00
09:00:00    23:00:00
06:00:00    23:45:00
```

It select only time before 00:00:00, but I need that it find in that piece.

Comment: If your timestamps included the date it'd probably be a lot easier.

Comment: It is great idea, but it like CONST data that can't store date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT time('now','+5 hours') as nowTime, time(restaurants.open_from) as openTime, time(restaurants.close_at) as closeTime,
CASE
    WHEN time(restaurants.open_from) > time(restaurants.close_at) THEN time('now','+5 hours')  >= time(restaurants.open_from) or time('now','+5 hours') < time(restaurants.close_at)
    when time(restaurants.open_from) < time(restaurants.close_at) THEN time('now','+5 hours')  >= time(restaurants.open_from) and time('now','+5 hours')  < time(restaurants.close_at)
    END is_opened
    from restaurants
WHERE is_opened >0
```

in my case it works, like I need.
output

```
06:16:03    06:00:00    23:45:00    1
06:16:03    06:00:00    23:45:00    1
06:16:03    06:00:00    04:00:00    1
06:16:03    06:00:00    02:00:00    1
```